# Twitter bootstrap Navbar justified links with logo/brand

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to justify my links and have my logo in the navbar. My links and logo will overlap on the left hand side. I want to make it so my links will justify to the right of my logo.

```
%body
   %nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
     .container-fluid
       .navbar-header
         %button.navbar-toggle.collapsed{"aria-controls" => "navbar", "aria-expanded" => "false", "data-target" => "#navbar", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :type => "button"}
        %span.sr-only Toggle navigation
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
  .container-fluid
    .navbar-header
      %a.navbar-brand{:href => "#"}
        %img{:alt => "IMage", :height => "50", :src => "/assets/logo.png"}

      %ul.nav.navbar-nav.nav-justified
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} link 
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} Link
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} link
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} link
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} link
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} link
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} link 
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} link
```

css

```
.navbar {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #004170;
   padding-top: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   font-size: 18px;

}

.navbar-nav.nav-justified > li{
   float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove `.navbar-nav` class from navbar code.

```
%ul.nav.navbar-nav.nav-justified
```

to

```
%ul.nav.nav-justified
```

If your navigation slightly move down then you can set below properties :

```
.nav-justified {
  width: 98%;
}
.nav-justified > li {
  float: none;
}
```

It works for me.